# Escape $() syntax in `docker exec`

Tags: bash, docker, command-substitution

I'm trying to run a command having a `$()` as an argument (no sure what that's called) that should be evaluated in a Docker container. For example:

```
docker exec mycontainer echo $(whoami)
```

When this is executed, `whoami` is run first, on the host machine, and so the host machine's user gets inserted. Instead, I would like the `whoami` command to be evaluated in the container such that the container's user is echo'd.

I found it very difficult to find any help on this. Alternatives I've tried that didn't work:

```
docker exec mycontainer 'echo $(whoami)'
docker exec mycontainer echo '$(whoami)'
docker exec mycontainer echo $$(whoami)
docker exec mycontainer echo \$(whoami)
```

How can this be achieved?

Comment: It's called a command substitution.  Doing `echo "$(command)"` is a superbly uselss way to write simply just `command`, and `echo $(command)` is an error unless you specifically require the shell to perform whitespace tokenization and wildcard expansion on the output from the command substitution before passing it to `echo`

Comment: @tripleee Thanks! `echo` is just used as an example here

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can pass in a single command, with arguments; but that single command can be `sh` or `bash`.

```
docker exec mycontainer sh -c 'echo $(whoami)'
```

If you need to use Bash syntax in the script fragment (which can really be arbitrarily complex; if you need single quotes inside the quotes, several common workarounds are available) then obviously use `bash` instead of `sh`.

Comment: Tangentially see also [Difference between `sh` and `bash`](/questions/5725296/difference-between-sh-and-bash)